# fetching data from api using baseUrl from variant in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, retrofit

I have two variants in my gradle file , each variant has different BaseUrl , for fetching data from api i"m using retrofit , now that i'm using BuildConfig to pass the BaseUrl based on the variant selected , if i pass whole url to baseUrl("") function , is it okey to leave @GET("") empty ? it is not working for me !! , i appreciate any help , Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use empty `GET` and pass full `url` with `@Url` retrofit annotation as query parameter

```
interface ApiService {
  @GET
  suspend fun getSimpson(@Url url: String): ApiModel
}
```

while invoking the method

```
getApiService().getSimpson(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply  , the baseUrl in retrofitBuilder() , should i leave empty , this one i mean Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("") ..

Comment: It does not matter, you could keep it same! `@Url` overrides the base url anyways!